# Is it possible to disable django related_name for a specific field?

Tags: django

Example:

```
class Route(models.Model):
    last_waypoint_visited = models.ForeignKey('WayPoint')

class WayPoint(models.Model):
    route = models.ForeignKey(Route)
```

Since WayPoint already has a reference to Route through the route field, I don't really need the field last_waypoint_visited to generate a back reference to Route.

Is it possible do just disable the back reference creation for the "last_waypoint_visited" field?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, disabling backward relations is a [documented feature](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name):

```
last_waypoint_visited = models.ForeignKey('WayPoint', related_name='+')
```

Comment: `None` ...or even `-` would make more sense.

Comment: `None` make sense, please make a pull request in [django](https://github.com/django/django).